# weak solution of PDE and apply Lax-Milgram

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Can someone help me for this problem?

> Write the weak formulation of:
>   $$\left\{\begin{align}
> -\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-5\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=f\quad&\text{in}\quad\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2\\
> u=0 \quad&\text{in}\quad\partial\Omega
> \end{align}\right.$$
>   Then apply Lax-Milgram to show existence of weak solution.

Using Green identity I found the following weak formulation:

Find $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ solution of
$$\int_\Omega u_x v_x+5\int_\Omega u_y v_y =\int_\Omega fv,\quad\forall\ v\in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

Is this correct?
How can I now apply Lax-Milgram?

Can I transform this equation using gradient or Laplace operator?
Thanks

Comment: Please, check if my edits in your post are correct.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) can help.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I now apply Lax-Milgram?*

You have to identify what are the bilinear form and the linear functional which correspond to your weak formulation.

In this case, the bilinear form is $B:H_0^1\times H_0^1\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$B[u,v]=\int_\Omega u_x v_x+5\int_\Omega u_y v_y.$$

And the linear functional is $\Lambda:H_0^1\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$\Lambda[v]=\int_\Omega fv.$$

Now, in order to prove existence of weak solution, you have to show that $B$ is continuous and coercive.

Comment: i know this B[u,v]=$∫u_x v_x=(u_x ,v_x )≤||u_x ||_(L^2 ) |v_x ||_(L^2 ) $ can I use that $||u_x ||_(L^2)  |v_x ||_(L^2 )≤||∇u||_(L^2)  ||∇v||_(L^2)  $

Comment: i know this B[u,v]=$∫u_x v_x=(u_x ,v_x )≤||〖u_x ||〗_(L^2 ) |〖v_x ||〗_(L^2 )$ can I use that $||u_x ||_(L^2)  |v_x ||_(L^2 )≤||∇u||_(L^2)  ||∇v||_(L^2)  $

Comment: Your first equality is not correct because there are other term.

Comment: Can I say that the norm of a component of the vector is smaller than the norm of the whole vector? (in this case the gradient)

||vx||<=||gradv||

Comment: @Mary According to the usual notation,
$$\|\nabla v\|_{L^2}^2:=\int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2=\int_\Omega (v_x^2+v_y^2)=\|v_x\|_{L^2}^2+\|v_y\|^2_{L^2}\geq \|v_x\|^2_{L^2}.$$
Therefore, $\|v_x\|_{L^2}\leq \|\nabla v\|_{L^2}$. Analogously, $\|v_y\|_{L^2}\leq \|\nabla v\|_{L^2}$.